# mysql: определить пол по имени (поиск значения из списка слов в поле, содержащем несколько слов)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select, find

Подскажите как сделать запрос в БД, чтобы выбрать только такие записи, в которых пользователь имеет определённый пол?

Т.е. у меня есть таблица `users`, в которой есть поле `name`, содержащее информацию о ФИО пользователя. Кроме того у меня есть список всех мужских имён (в общем случае только нужный мне список имен, типа `Андей,Иван,Пётр`)

С одной стороны запрос можно было бы сделать так:

```
select name 
from users
where find_in_set(name, "андрей,иван,пётр")>0
```

Но проблема в том, что в `name` содержится именно ФИО, т.е. несколько слов.
Подскажите как корректно решить данную задачу?

Comment: *в name содержится именно ФИО, т.е. несколько слов* Используя строковые функции (вероятно, SUBSTRING_INDEX лучше всего), вырезать только имя, и потом связывать с таблицей имён.

Comment: @Akina, но может быть проблема - существовать и `Иванов Иван` и `Иван Иванов`. Возможно в этом случае можно сделать подзапрос и разложить в таблицу поле name(т.е. будет несколько записей с отдельными словами)

Comment: Если у тебя ещё и содержимое поля произвольно форматировано (есть и ФИО, и ИОФ, и ИО, и ИФ, и ФИ, и т.п.) - то поздравляю, ты на поле Тысячи Грабель. Бросай эту мелкую задачку и начинай заниматься нормализацией своих данных.

Comment: @Akina, если бы это были мои данные... такого бы не было :)

Comment: Задача на самом деле не разрешима, просто потому, что у человека может не быть имени или быть абсолютно "нестандартным" (что такое стандартно ?) https://habr.com/ru/post/146901/

Comment: @Mike, это конечно та, но если основным запросом можно захватить 99% записей, то остальные легко уже и в ручном режиме пройти

Comment: Ну если так подходить и ФИО русское, может начать с последней буквы ФИО (отчества), если "ч" - мужчина :)

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте (перечислить мужские имена) так:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name REGEXP "Василий |Иван |Евгений " = 1
```

да функции для работы с строками типа SUBSTRING_INDEX будут быстрее, но и кода писать больше (если запросы будут постоянные то лучше наверное с строковыми функциями, а если не частые и не много данных то можно и регулярку оставить)

Comment: Стрельнёт на "Иванов-Зипермолниеносный Идиосинкразий Парамонович", например. Что явно некорректно.

Comment: да фамилии или отчества могут попасть(

Comment: Вот... для REGEXP надо и искомое, и значение обрамлять разделителями, что вряд ли удобно. А при разборе - хотя бы по таблице имён можно будет пользовать индекс.

Comment: думаю по 1му пробелу будет достаточно (поправил код)

Comment: Да, наверное... если не найдётся имён таких, что на них заканчивается какое-то другое имя (впрочем, навскидку придумать такое не смог).

Answer (score 2):

Есть же оператор IN

```
..WHERE `name` IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')
```

https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Ну русским же по белому товарищ пишет, что у него в поле name - полное ФИО.

Comment: Проблем-то SELECT ... SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 1) as `first_name` from ... WHERE `first_name` IN (..)

Comment: См. коммент автора к вопросу. Там не всё так просто.

Comment: @Евгений, такой способ действительно подходит, но к сожалению он не универсален и если очень много записей, то ручная правка мелких неточностей станет ресурсоемким

Answer (score 1):

По идее, если считать, что большая часть записей имеет вид `Фамилия Имя`, то можно сделать такой запрос:

```
select name
from inventor
where find_in_set(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1), "Абрам,Аваз,Аввакум,Август,Августин,Авдей,Авраам,Автандил,Агап,Агафон,Аггей,Адам,Адис,Адольф,Адриан,Азамат,Айдар,Айнур,Айрат,Аким,Алан,Алей,Александр,Алексей,Али,Альберт,Альфред,Амадей,Амадеус,Амаяк,Амвросий,Ананий,Анастасий,Анатолий,Анвар,Ангел,Андоим,Андрей,Аникита,Антон,Арам,Арий,Аристарх,Аркадий,Арман,Арно,Арнольд,Арон,Арсен,Арсений,Арслан,Артем,Артемий,Артур,Архип,Аскар,Аскольд,Аслан,Афанасий,Ахмет,Ашот,Бальтазар,Бежен,Бенедикт,Берек,Бернард,Бертран,Богдан,Болеслав,Борис,Бронислав,Булат,Вадим,Валентин,Валерий,Вальтер,Варфоломей,Василий,Вацлав,Велизар,Венедикт,Вениамин,Викентий,Виктор,Вилли,Вильгельм,Виссарион,Виталий,Витольд,Владимир,Владислав,Владлен,Володар,Вольдемар,Всеволод,Вячеслав,Гавриил,Галактион,Гарри,Гастон,Гаяс,Гевор,Геннадий,Генрих,Георгий,Геракл,Геральд,Герасим,Герман,Глеб,Гордей,Гордон,Горислав,Градимир,Григорий,Гурий,Густав,Давид,Дамир,Даниил,Даниэль,Данияр,Дарий,Дементий,Демид,Демосфен,Демьян,Денис,Джамал,Джордан,Дмитрий,Добрыня,Дональд,Донат,Дорофей,Евгений,Евграф,Евдоким,Евсевий,Евсей,Евстафий,Егор,Елеазар,Елисей,Емельян,Еремей,Ермолай,Ерофей,Ефим,Ефрем,Жан,Ждан,Жорж,Захар,Зиновий,Ибрагим,Иван,Игнатий,Игорь,Илларион,Ильдар,Ильнар,Ильнур,Илья,Ильяс,Иннокентий,Иоанн,Иосиф,Ипполит,Искандер,Ислам,Камиль,Карим,Карл,Кирилл,Клим,Кондрат,Константин,Корней,Кузьма,Лавр,Лаврентий,Лев,Леон,Леонид,Леонтий,Леопольд,Лука,Лукьян,Любим,Макар,Максим,Максимилиан,Марат,Марк,Марсель,Мартин,Матвей,Мирон,Мирослав,Митрофан,Михаил,Михей,Мишель,Мстислав,Мурат,Муслим,Назар,Назарий,Наиль,Натан,Наум,Нестор,Никанор,Никита,Никифор,Николай,Никон,Нифонт,Норман,Овидий,Олан,Олег,Олесь,Онисим,Орест,Осип,Оскар,Павел,Петр,Платон,Прохор,Равиль,Радик,Радмир,Радомир,Раду,Рамазан,Рамиль,Ратибор,Ратмир,Рафаэль,Рахим,Рашид,Ринат,Ричард,Роберт,Родион,Ролан,Роман,Ростислав,Рудольф,Руслан,Рустам,Сабир,Савва,Савелий,Салим,Самвел,Самсон,Святослав,Севастьян,Семён,Серафим,Сергей,Соломон,Спартак,Спиридон,Станислав,Степан,Стефан,Сулейман,Султан,Тагир,Тамерлан,Тарас,Теодор,Тигран,Тимофей,Тимур,Тихон,Трофим,Умар,Устин,Фаддей,Фарид,Федор,Федот,Феликс,Феодосий,Фердинанд,Фидель,Филимон,Филипп,Флор,Флорентий,Фома,Франц,Фридрих,Фуад,Харитон,Хасан,Христиан,Христос,Христофор,Шамиль,Эдвард,Эдгар,Эдуард,Эльдар,Эмиль,Эмин,Эмир,Эммануил,Эрик,Эрнест,Юлиан,Юлий,Юрий,Юсуф,Юхим,Яким,Яков,Ян,Януарий,Яромир,Ярослав,Ясон")
```

А все остальное прошерстить руками, но так хотелось бы универсальный метод, поскольку если записей не в нужном формате много, то ручная правка будет очень ресурсоемкой

Comment: я вполне могу себе представить следующие __фамилии__: `Аваз,Август,Адис,Алан,Али,...` и еще много... Как вы планируете "вручную" разобрать например `Алан Август` - где здесь что? ;)

Comment: @MaxU - только фидбеком этих пользователей, ну с Алан Августом еще понятно, но вот с `Марта Август` могут быть проблемы. Самое главное, что пользователям потребовались полы, поэтому такой запрос будет одноразовым (хотя и по большой базе имен), а впоследствии при заводе нового пользователя будет выставляться и пол, так что проблемы не будет